# Not being able to use c# value in javascript in cshtml file for maps

Tags: c#, razor

I have some nullable values coming from my c# code. They are longitude and latitude.

I have this code

```
<script>
    @if (Model.crisis.Longitude.HasValue)
    {
        var lng = Model.crisis.Longitude.Value;
        var lat = Model.crisis.Latitude.Value;
        <text>
            window.onload = function() {
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 13,
                    center: { lat: @(lat), lng: @(lng) },
                  //  center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.roadmap,
                    disableDefaultUI: true
                };

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(@lat, @lng),

                });

                marker.setMap(map);
            }
        </text>
    }
</script>
```

Props from server

```
public double? Latitude { get; set; }
public double? Longitude { get; set; }
```

My map doesn't show as it doesn't center at the given long and lat. If I hardcode values then it works like a charm. Am I missing something? For me it seems, that I cannot use nullable values here. Is it so?

Comment: try `var lng = Model.crisis.Longitude.Value ?? 0; var lat = Model.crisis.Latitude.Value ?? 0;` if it works I'll explain

Comment: It didn't worked. I also had to do var lng = Model.crisis.Longitude ?? 0;

Comment: If you use` var lng = Model.crisis.Longitude.Value ?? 0; var lat = Model.crisis.Latitude.Value ?? 0;`,what are the values of `lng` and `lat`?And why you are using `<text></text>` in `<script></script>`?